# How to detect logout event with the Facebook Android API v4?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I post here because I've got a problem.
I'm working on a new android application , and I want to know how I can detect when a user is disconnecting (facebook logout button), because I want to refresh my UI at this moment.

I have been watched the official documentation, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this also

```
 if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null)
 {
   Log.v("User is login","YES");

 }
else
{
         Log.v("User is not login","OK");
      LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(WelcomeActivity1.this, (Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends","user_birthday","user_about_me","email")));
 }
```

Comment: This answers not really the event based part of the question since you have to poll using this code. For logout/login callbacks use @Nicolás Arias answer.

Answer (score 27):

You can set a listener on the `onCreate()` method on your activity

```
AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

            if (currentAccessToken == null){
                //User logged out
            }
        }
    };
```

You need to import `com.facebook.AccessToken` and `com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker`

When you create the instance of AccessTokenTracker it *implicitly* starts tracking. For **stopping** tracking you should call `AccessTokenTracker.stopTracking()` e.g. in `onDestroy()` to not receive anymore events when not needed/wanted and especially to not leak memory!

You can get any time if the user is logged in/out by calling

```
AccessToken at = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
```

If the user is not logged in, you get a `null` value.

For further reference please check the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessTokenTracker/

Comment: Its also import to call `AccessTokenTracker.stopTracking()` e.g. in `onDestroy()` to stop receiving events e.g. in an already destroyed activity!